# Sorting characters by popularity in C

Tags: c, sorting

I wrote a code for listing the occurrences of characters in the string. It works, but I was wondering, is it possible to put it in order? For example descending. Sounds simple, but I'm using two arrays here and I don't know how could I possibly link them so that they wouldn't be messed up after sorting. I read that in C++ I could use std::pair but from what I found, there is no substitute for that in C.

Isn't there a simple way just to sort it so that I could have a list of most/least popular characters? I started going into bubble sort but whatever I choose, there will still be no link between the two arrays.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int hits[26] = { 0 };
    char letters[26] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    char *line;
    int i;

    printf("Write the line:\n");
    scanf("%25[^\n]", line);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        if (!isalpha(line[i]))
            continue;
        hits[(int)(tolower(line[i]) - 'a')]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c is showing up %d times.\n", letters[i], hits[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe there is a simple mistake I'm making in my approach, if so, then I'd be happy to have it pointed out.

Comment: 1) You need allocate for `line`. E.g `char line[26];`

Comment: I guess you should read about [`struct`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you, changed it, didn't notice it was missing.

Comment: I think you need to include `ctype.h` for using `isalpha`.

Comment: @LinK: you are not supposed to *fix* the code in the question, it makes the comments and answers inconsistent.  Furthermore, a size of `[26]` for the line is probably not appropriate. Either use a larger array or just read one character at a time with `getchar()` until `EOF`.  Note also that you should cast the `char` arguments to `isalpha()` and `tolower()` as `(unsigned char)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make the fixes suggested in @artm's answer.

But in regards to your sorting question. The C standard library has one (or more, depending on the version) routines for sorting an array of any kind. The most common is `qsort(3)`. The rub is that you have to give the routine a function which it can use to compare elements of the array. So you need a way of storing both the character and its occurrence together, and you need to write that comparison function.

I'd suggest taking @jack's comment and using an array of structures. Each struct would be something like:

```
struct letter {
    char character;
    int count;
};
```

to group both a character and its number of occurrences. Then allocate an array of these, one for each letter (rather than just an `int[]` as you have now).

```
struct letter letters[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    letters[i] = (struct letter){ (char)(i + 'a'), 0 };
}
```

In your loop searching through the line retrieved from the user, update the `letter.count` field for the corresponding letter each time it is seen.

Then you can use the standard library `qsort(3)` function to sort the array of letters by the counts within them. To use the function, you need a comparison function, which tells the library the ordering of two elements (greater or lesser).

The comparison function must have the signature: `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)`. The `void*` point to individual elements in your `letters` array, so you need to cast them to `struct letter` and compare the counts within them. It might look something like this (untested):

```
int letter_cmp(const void* first, const void* second) {
    struct letter* first_letter = (struct letter *) first;
    struct letter* second_letter = (struct letter*) second;
    if (first_letter->count == second_letter->count) {
        return 0;
    } else if (first_letter->count < second_letter->count) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You'd then make the call to the `qort(3)` function as follows.

```
qsort(&letters[0], sizeof(letters), sizeof(struct letter), &letter_cmp);
```

The first argument is the start of the array. The second is the size of the array in elements. The third is the size of each element, and fourth is your comparison function.

After this call returns, the `letters` array has been sorted in order of increasing `count`. So `letters[0].character` gives you the character with the lowest `count`, and `letters[25].character` gives that with the highest (most occurrences).

Comment: Did you compile the code?  I believe the assignment `letters[i] = { (char)(i + 'a'), 0 };` needs to use a compound literal `letters[i] = (struct letters){ (char)(i + 'a'), 0 };`.  It looks like a cast; it isn't actually a cast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, I missed that. I edited the post, thanks.

Comment: @bnaecker I had the same problem and it worked when I wrote letters[i] = letters[(char)(i + 'a'), 0]. Is that alright as well? I don't understand that line in general, could you please explain? I assume it fills array with letters from a to z, but what does the zero do? Also, I have no idea how to update the letter.count in the loop, I tried letter[i].count++ but it doesn't seem to be linking it with the character array. I'm sorry if this seems dumb, I really want to understand it though. Thank you.

Comment: @LinK The syntax you have in your comment is not correct. You're *indexing* the array `letters` when you use square brackets `[]`, and actually reading past the end of the array by adding `'a'` to the index `i`. (Note the use of curly braces `{}` in my code.) The goal of that line is to initialize all the `character` field of each `struct letter` in the array `letters[26]`, just like you guessed. The zero is to initialize the count to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You used pointer `line` without initialising it - UB.

You should dynamically allocate for it, or simply using a static array with some proper provisioning - eg, 1000 characters (including '\0') would be enough.

```
char line[1000] = "";
```

You don't really need to limit the input line to 25 chars like this:

```
scanf("%25[^\n]", line);
```

Instead, use `fgets` would be much better:

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
```

Btw, you don't really need a cast here:

```
hits[tolower(line[i]) - 'a')]++;
```

Then your solution should work.

Comment: thank you, I'll update that but my solution is... already working... I'm trying to sort it. Right now I'm checking out struct since according to Jack is the way to go, so I'll see what I can do.

Comment: sure you can make an array[26] of `struct`, each having two fields 1) the character and 2) the counter. You still need to initialise that array manually as you did with individual arrays.

Comment: In the line using `tolower()`, you're right that the original `int` cast was unnecessary.  However, both the original and the revised version are missing a cast that could be important — you should convert `line[i]` to an `unsigned char` because if plain `char` is a signed type, `line[i]` might be negative (accented characters in particular).  You really need: `hits[tolower[(unsigned char)line[i] - 'a']++;` — and similar comments apply to `isalpha()` too.  All the functions in `<ctype.h>` take an unsigned char or EOF converted to `int` as the input.

Answer (score 1):

An pointer to a structure could be used and allocated as needed. The pointer can be used similar to an array but can expand by using `realloc`. This would allow inclusion of upper and lower case letters or any range of `char`'s desired.
This gets characters from stdin until either EOF or newline so there isn't much of a restriction on the number of characters input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct charcount {
    char ch;
    int count;
};

void showeach ( struct charcount *ary, int size) {
    int index = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    for ( index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        if ( index % 3 == 0) {
            printf ( "\n");
        }
        if ( index && index % 48 == 0) {
            printf ( "\npress enter\n");
            while ( ( ch = fgetc ( stdin)) != '\n') {
                if ( ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input. EOF\n");
                }
            }
        }
        //show the characters and the count
        printf ( " %4c", ary[index].ch);

        printf ( "%6d      "
        , ary[index].count);
    }
    printf ( "\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t elements = 0;
    size_t loop = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int found = 0;
    struct charcount *chno = NULL;//so realloc will work on first call
    struct charcount *temp = NULL;
    struct charcount swap;

    //get each character until newline or EOF
    while ( ( ( ch = fgetc ( stdin)) != EOF) && ch != '\n') {
        if ( ch && isalpha ( ch)) {//restict to letters
            ch = tolower ( ch);//restrict to lower case
            found = 0;
            for ( loop = 0; loop < elements; loop++) {
                if ( ch == chno[loop].ch) {
                    chno[loop].count++;
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( !found) {//new element. reallocate
                if ( ( temp = realloc ( chno, sizeof ( *chno) * (elements + 1))) == NULL) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "problem allocating\n");
                    free ( chno);
                    return 1;
                }
                chno = temp;
                chno[elements].ch = ch;
                chno[elements].count = 1;
                //sort by letter
                for ( loop = elements; loop > 0; loop--) {
                    if ( chno[loop].ch < chno[loop - 1].ch) {
                        swap = chno[loop];
                        chno[loop] = chno[loop - 1];
                        chno[loop - 1] = swap;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                elements++;
            }
        }
    }

    showeach ( chno, elements);

    //sort by count
    for ( index = 1; index < elements; index++) {
        for ( loop = index; loop > 0; loop--) {
            if ( chno[loop].count > chno[loop - 1].count) {
                swap = chno[loop];
                chno[loop] = chno[loop - 1];
                chno[loop - 1] = swap;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    showeach ( chno, elements);

    if ( chno) {
        free ( chno);//free allocated memory
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes because you use `line` to read bytes with `scanf()` but it is an uninitialized pointer, so storing bytes to it invokes undefined behavior.

- You can correct this problem by defining `line` as an array: `char line[80];`
- Alternately, you can modify the code to read an arbitrarily long line, one byte at a time with `getchar()`.

To print stats in decreasing order, you can use an array of structures and sort it or simply iteratively print the largest number and reset it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int hits['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0 };
    int c, i, max;

    printf("Write the line:\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            hits[tolower(c) - 'a'] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (;;) {
        for (i = max = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; i++) {
            if (hits[i] > hits[max])
                max = i;
        }
        if (hits[max] == 0)
            break;
        printf("%c is showing up %d times.\n", 'a' + max, hits[max]);
        hits[max] = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may I ask what is the for(;;) loop doing? I'm pretty sure I understand almost everything except for that. Also, the 'a' being added in the last printf (as well as 1 added in the earlier for loop) is it because of the [\0] array subscript? Arrays are still confusing to me...

Comment: `for (;;)` is a `for` loop with no condition, hence an infinite loop. This loop will be exited when the largest hit number will come out as `0`: `if (hits[max] == 0) break;`.  The `'a'` added in the printf argument is there to convert the array index into the corresponding lower case letter. It is the inverse of the operation `tolower(c) - 'a'` that converts a lowercase letter into an offset into the `hits` array.  The `hits` array has 26 slots if the lowercase letters are consecutive (as is the case in ASCII). The first entry (index 0) in the `hits` array corresponds to letter `'a'`, etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I really liked your solution for showing me another way of sorting without using struct. Thanks! :)